# Value assignment in C#

Tags: c#, initialization

Without initialization how is it possible to assign values to arrays?

```
string[] s={"all","in","all"};

I mean why did not the compile show error?.Normally we need to 
initialize ,before assign values.
```

Comment: Just like you showed... Or I don't get the question-part here.

Comment: I'm not sure I get the question.

Comment: Have we discovered the stackoverflow equivalent of 'how is babby formed?'

Comment: @Seth  Smart answer.But Just i finised schooling.I am  learning C#.If you know answer of your question explain me Mr Mega Genious.

Comment: @ Ross & @ Henk: Sorry for not making my question clear

Comment: Thanks everybody for clearing the doubt.

Comment: You should read section 7.5.10 of the C# specification; it answers all your questions that you've posted here -- how array, object and collection initializers work in C# 3.0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's just syntactic sugar.

This:

```
string[] s = {"all","in","all"};
```

is compiled to the same code as:

```
string[] tmp = new string[3];
tmp[0] = "all";
tmp[1] = "in";
tmp[2] = "all";
string[] s = tmp;
```

Note that the array reference is not assigned to `s` until all the elements have been assigned. That isn't important in this particular case where we're declaring a *new* variable, but it would make a different in this situation:

```
string[] s = { "first", "second" };
s = new string[] { s[1], s[0] };
```

The same is true for object and collection initializers - the variable is only assigned at the end.

Comment: Is this relaxation for Array only?

Comment: ooh I found a bug in John Skeet's code!  s is not defined, line 2. I think you meant tmp[0] = "all";

Comment: @generix: What exactly do you mean by "relaxation"? It's just a form of syntax.

Comment: @Neil heheh...I confirm...it did just happen :D

Comment: @Jon Regardless of "bug", yet another interesting and informative answer.

Comment: Interestingly enough, int[] x = {1, 2, 3} does NOT generate the same code as int[] tmp = new int[3]; tmp[0] = 1; tmp[1] = 2; tmp[2] = 3; int[] x = tmp. :-)

Comment: @Eric: Now you've got me intrigued now... will have to investigate :)

Comment: You'll be investigating our "private implementation details" then. (Integer arrays initialized with a block of constants are stored in a binary block named "PrivateImplemetationDetails" that can be passed to a special array initializer helper that efficiently blits the block into the array; that's much faster than copying in each element one at a time.)

Comment: I figured it would be something a bit like that. And you can't do that with strings because of garbage collection? Presumably you could do it with any immutable value type though...

Comment: Why would they want to do it with strings? There's `ldstr` for strings.

Comment: @Pavel: Actually I withdraw my garbage collection comment - this is only appropriate for constants anyway. But `ldstr` is only for a single strings, not arrays of strings, right?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to declare an array variable without initialization.

Check this out
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0a7fscd0%28VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: declaring an array without initialization would just be `string[] s` the example above provides values which the string is initialized with.

Comment: the example above provides values which the string *array* is initialized with

Answer (score 3):

You aren't "assigning a value to array". You are initializing a variable of type "reference to array". The value with which you initialize it is a reference to an array which was created by the use of short array initializer syntax `{...}`. While it is only permissible in initializer of variables of array type, it is exactly equivalent to `new T[] { ... }`, where `T` is deduced from type of variable.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to know why

```
 string[] s={"all","in","all"};
```

works when you would expect to be required to initialize the array first like this :

```
string[] s = new string[];
```

or

```
string[] s = new string[] {"all","in","all"};
```

The answer is just compiler magic.  The compiler knows based on the initialization how big to make the array so it just does it behind the scenes for you.  Much like the `var` keyword, the point is to limit the amount of redundant information you're required to type.

Comment: Is this relaxation for arrays only? Pesron a={ Name="somename"} ??

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] s = new string[] { "all","in","all"};
```

and its shorthand version

```
string[] s = {"all","in","all"};
```

are the same thing. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453(VS.71).aspx) (Initializing Arrays section) for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

The `{"all","in","all"}` part is the initialization. the `new string[]` part can be omitted because the curly braces and string are short hand notation. Take a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0a7fscd0.aspx) on Single Dimension Arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the new string[] part in C#3 or higher - this works fine

```
string[] s = { "all","in","all"};
```

It's just a case of the compiler being a bit smarter and working out what you mean - the back end IL will be the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can do so simply because it is allowed, doing so in two steps is not necessary so this is the shorthand. Consider it sugar.